# Undeploy a failed Mule app

Tags: mule, esb

We have a Live mule server (Community edition ) 3.3.0 running on a Windows 2008 server.
We have several apps running on it.

We tried to hotdeploy a new app in it. It failed saying some port was already in use/bind - this was a JMX port. However we were unable to undeploy it. It didn't create any anchor file as it had failed deployment so we couldn't do the clean undeploy. When we tried to delete the exploded folder it didn't allow as it said the jars in the lib were in use.

We tried to re-deploy the same file with fix again but it had no effect.

Question is irrespective of what caused out application to fail - how can one undeploy or take out a Mule app (failed) completely? It doesn't have anchor file and trying to delete says jar in use. Only way we could do was to stop mule and then delete the folder and restart Mule - totally unacceptable in production environment.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known bug on 3.3.0 that was fixed on 3.3.1](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6363).

Comment: Thanks David. We are using 3.3.0 as our production environment and will take time to upgrade (All sorts of reasons!!) Is there a patch I can apply in 3.3.0 standalone itself? Thanks in advance

Comment: Alas no patch for CE, only for EE: upgrade is your way out :) BTW consider upgrading to 3.4.0.